# Match the € symbol in re with python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to match the € symbol in a string but I get a strange behaviour when using the special character "?". It works as expected with normal characters

```
import re

print re.match(r'a?1', 'a1')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x3a2ba58>

print re.match(r'a?1', '1')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x3a2ba58>
```

but with the € symbol I get this output

```
print re.match(r'€?1', '€1')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x3a2ba58>

print re.match(r'€?1', '1')
None
```

Any idea about what's going on? I suspect it's something related to unicode.
I'm using python 2.7.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

€ is not an ascii character, so you need to use unicode matching:

```
print re.match(ur'€?1', u'€1', flags=re.UNICODE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7ffde0084bf8>

print re.match(ur'€?1', u'1', flags=re.UNICODE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7ffde0084bf8>
```

Comment: I had already tried print re.match(ur'€?1', u'1') 
I didn't post it because it didn't work. After that I realised it was a problem of the console embedded in my IDE. print re.match(ur'€?1', u'1') works as expected. Thank you anyway for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You will notice that the question has had the `python2.7` tag added, as this question is version-specific.

By default Python assumes that your source will be UTF-8 encoded. It sees the Euro symbol as a sequence of UTF-8 bytes which appear as individual bytes in your string:

```
>>> r'€?1'
'\xe2\x82\xac?1'
```

So you specified matching using a pattern that requires the ASCII bytes `\xe2\x82` to be followed optionally by an `\xac` byte and finally a mandatory digit `1`.

Explicitly identifying your Unicode literals as such will cure the problem.

```
>>> m = re.match(u'€?1', u'€1')
>>> m.start(), m.end()
(0, 2)
>>> m = re.match(u'€?1', u'1')
>>> m.start(), m.end()
(0, 1)
```

Moving to Python 3, the interpreter assumes that all string literals are Unicode unless they are explicitly tagged as bytestrings using a `b'...'` literal, so the problem doesn't occur:

```
>>> r'€?1'
'€?1'
>>> m = re.match(r'€?1', '€1')
>>> m.start(), m.end()
(0, 2)
```